# How to execute commands stored in array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute a shell script like below

```sh
cmds=('uptime' 'free -m' 'nproc')
for cmd in ${cmds[@]};
do
echo $($cmd)
done
```

Execution is breaking when it comes to `free -m` execution because of space.

```sh
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ bash for_my_script.sh
 03:42:50 up 56 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         499928      108516       43204        1844      348208      366140
Swap:             0           0           0
for_my_script.sh: line 5: -m: command not found

1
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

I tried iterating with for by storing commands in variable

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cmds="uptime,free -m"
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ for cmd in "${cmds//,/ }"; do echo "$($cmd)"; done
uptime: invalid option -- 'm'
```

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cmds="uptime,'free -m'"
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ for cmd in "${cmds//,/ }"; do echo "$($cmd)"; done
uptime: invalid option -- 'm'
```

With no success.

is touching `IFS` is the only way for this type of problem?
any inputs are much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see in your code where you would actually **execute** the commands. BTW, please tag your question properly: I don't believe that you really want to use _sh_, since you explicitly invoke your command by _bash_. I suggest that you remove you _sh_ tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (edit: previously) accepted answer still involves [unquoted strings](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), which are discouraged and error-prone. You *could* use `eval` as @Fravadona suggests, but `eval` is also [hard to work with properly/safely](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Instead, consider creating functions to wrap the commands you want to run; then you don't need to deal with nested arguments within strings. Functions also makes it easy to compose more complex behavior (pipelines, conditionals, etc.) without complicating the execution loop. Something like:

```
do_free() { free -m; }

cmds=(uptime do_free nproc)
for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
  "$cmd"  # notice that you don't need echo $("$cmd"); it's generally redundant
done
```

You could create wrappers for `uptime` and `nproc` too for consistency, but it's not necessary as long as you don't need to pass any arguments.

For a more complete example of what I'm suggesting see this [heartbeat script](https://gist.github.com/dimo414/10d6f162fb6d72f517a041d28d92314f) and the `COMMANDS` array in particular.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case the right way **would be** to use `eval`:

```sh
cmds=('uptime' 'free -m' 'nproc')
for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"
do
    eval "$cmd"
done
```

**But you need to make sure that the content of `cmd` is exactly like you would type it in the terminal**

<sub>**`eval` is evil**, when you don't know the right way to use it</sub>

---

Let's see a few examples:

```
# cmd='echo "a     b"'
#
# eval "$cmd"
a     b
#
# $cmd
"a b"
#
```

```
# cmd='echo a; echo b'
#
# eval "$cmd"
a
b
# $cmd
a; echo b
#
```

```
# cmd='echo;'
#
# eval "$cmd"

# $cmd
bash: echo;: command not found...
#
```